# why my mysql command is available in cmd but not in powershell

Tags: mysql, windows

I have installed the mysql, The problem is that when I type `mysql -version` it's showing the version in cmd but the same code is throwing error in PowerShell

```
mysql --version
mysql : The term 'mysql' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,  
or operable program
```

can this cause any issue when I start developing my project or it won't even work?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162002/mysql-recognized-by-cmd-but-not-powershell

Comment: Please spell mysql correctly in your command.

Answer (score -1):

Missclick "y"
m**y**sql --version